# Unicode character in email not throwing exception

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, email-validation, system.net.mail

I have an email address with unicode character. It is not throwing exception.
I am using .Net Mail Address overloaded constructor. MSDN says it will throw FormatException when address contains non-ASCII characters. But I am unable to reproduce exception.

```
var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("ñ@c.com","test", Encoding.UTF8);
```

If this is recognized email address then I am searching for a character which will throw exception to unit test.

Comment: Every character is a UNICODE character. Where does it say it'll throw an exception? The documentation says it'll throw that if it's "not in recognized format", nothing is mentioned about characters https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/591bk9e8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This overload version documentation says it will throw exception. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f52hswkf(v=vs.110).aspx . Basically I need an email address to unit test if Email fails for unicode characters or not.

Comment: Have you tried with some chinese characters? The "non-ASCII" could actually be "non-Latin1" and ñ is quite acceptable there.

Comment: Yes I tried many chinese Japanese and other characters too. No success

Answer (score 2):

The documentation seems to be outdated. Unicode characters are supported since .NET 4.0 in the mail addresses, see the following blog article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ncl/archive/2009/08/06/what-s-new-in-system-net-mail.aspx

Comment: That only mentions the *display name*, not *address* being allowed with different encodings.

Answer (score 2):

The source code is quite clear on the subject - there is no check for unicode characters.

This means that the documentation is outdated - for quite a while, unicode domain names have been supported. The only thing remaining of the old checks is only applied when the SMTP server you're using to send the e-mail *doesn't* support Email Address Internationalization.

In other words, don't validate unicode content in e-mail addresses as an error - it's *not* invalid.